@typescript-eslint/no-unsafe-assignment: "Unsafe assignment of an `any` value" error caused by nullish coalescing an array to undefined
Here is the setup, a simple React component that accepts an optional array of strings. Using typescript: "^5.5.2" and @typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin: "^7.13.1"
type Props = {
  list?: string[];
};

function ListComponent({ list }: Props) {
  return (
    <ul>
      {list?.map((string) => <li>{string}</li>}
    </ul>
  );
}

This code fails linting at maybeList.data ?? undefined:
function ParentComponent() {
  const maybeList: { data: string[] | null } = client.list.get.useQuery();
  return (
    <ListComponent
      list={maybeList.data ?? undefined} // Error: Unsafe assignment of an `any` value.  @typescript-eslint/no-unsafe-assignment
    />
  );
}

But this code succeeds maybeList.data ?? []:
function ParentComponent() {
  const maybeList: { data: string[] | null } = client.list.get.useQuery();
  return (
    <ListComponent
      list={maybeList.data ?? []}
    />
  );
}

I cannot understand how maybeList.data ?? undefined is being interpreted as any. Is this a bug? Or do I not understand TS?
